# How to give wine prefix more space?

Tags: software-installation, wine, disk-usage

I installed a video game and wanted to understand it so I tried to install unofficial Czech translation. Unfortunately installer thinks I have 0 Mb of available space because of wine prefix. Can I somehow assign more space to wine prefix ?
I'm also pretty sure it isn't problem with real disc space because I have used only 20% of all space.
Apparently, wine prefixes have only assigned space available instead of using all space of hard drive.
I'm using PlayOnLinux. Installer says I have 0 Mb available if I install unsupported software or open exe in this virtual drive, so I'm kinda out of choices.
*Note: I'm Linux user (or how I like to call myself : Sudomancer) for 5 days so I really don't know much about Ubuntu or Wine.*

Comment: Is it normal that wine prefix uses so much disk space, while still empty, no game? I mean like 800mb. Are that dlls, registry...?

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently, wine prefixes have only assigned space available instead of using all space of hard drive

This is not correct. A wineprefix is just a folder that Wine uses to store files in, it doesn't have a specific amount of allocated space. (It looks like PlayOnLinux stores its wineprefixes in `~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/`; if you look in one of the folders there for a folder called `drive_c`, you'll see something that looks a lot like an ordinary Windows installation.)

It's possible that your application is reporting the wrong amount of free disk space because it uses a Windows API that Wine hasn't implemented properly yet, or because the API is buggy – the only thing I can suggest is to change the version of Windows that Wine tries to emulate, which has solved similar problems in the past for me. You can do that by pressing "Configure Wine" in the Wine tab of PlayOnLinux.

If that doesn't work, there's a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335620/226269) – maybe the answer there would help in your situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, question you linked does not work.  I bet you are right about API. Apparently, installer was created using Clickteam install creator pro. Do you know about fix ? Maybe codeware crossover but I don't want to spend so much money on something what may and may not work.